# How to handle FirebaseAuth User vs the User from the project users collection of cloud_store?

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, model

I am really uncertain of how to handle the data "duplication" of the signed in user from FirebaseAuth and the project own User model fed by the `users` collection I create from FirebaseAuth sign ups.

For example, creating a `UserAvatar` widget that shows the signed in user display name and photo URL. Should I user the FireAuth User or my own `users` collection?

What would be the pros and the cons?

Answer (score 2):

There are several considerations to take into account when deciding whether to use the FirebaseAuth user object or a separate user object from your own database.

One consideration is the purpose of the user object. If you are using the user object for authentication purposes, such as checking whether a user is logged in or verifying their credentials, then it may be more appropriate to use the FirebaseAuth user object. This is because the FirebaseAuth user object is specifically designed for these types of tasks, and it is directly tied to the user's authentication state in your Firebase project.

On the other hand, if you are using the user object to store additional information about the user that is not related to authentication, such as the user's display name or profile photo, then it may be more appropriate to use your own user object from the database. This is because the FirebaseAuth user object is limited in the amount of information it can store, and it is not intended to be used as a general-purpose user object.

There are pros and cons to both approaches. Using the FirebaseAuth user object has the advantage of being directly tied to the user's authentication state, which can be convenient for certain types of tasks. However, it is limited in the amount of information it can store, and it may not be the most flexible solution if you need to store a large amount of information about your users.

On the other hand, using your own user object from the database allows you to store more information about your users, and it gives you more flexibility in terms of the data model. However, it requires additional work to keep the user object in sync with the FirebaseAuth user object, and it may introduce additional complexity to your codebase.

Ultimately, the best approach will depend on your specific needs and the requirements of your project. You may find that a combination of both approaches works best for your use case, or that one approach is more suitable than the other.